# Does Retrofit or OkHttp limit number of parallel requests?

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I use *RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()* and *Schedulers.io()*, so *Dispatcher* isn't used and *maxRequests* and *maxRequestsPerHost* not a problem. *Schedulers.io()* creates infinite number of threads.

The problem is when I run 10 requests and then 1 more while previous not finished this 1 request takes longer time to start. If 10 requests finished the next request run immediately.
When I have a several requests running I see in logs that *Call.execute()* is called and then request started only after 6 seconds. When there are no active requests, new request starts immediately. So is it limitation of android or some network libraries?

Answer (score 4):

Use [OkHttp Dispatcher](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-dispatcher/).

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20));
dispatcher.setMaxRequests(20);
dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(1);

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
   .dispatcher(dispatcher)
   .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
   .baseUrl(HttpUrl.get("https://example.com/"))
   .client(okHttpClient)
   .build();
```

Comment: Just to add here, I checked the defaults values on v4.10.0 of okhttp and found `maxRequests = 64` and `maxRequestsPerHost = 5`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, configure this in OkHttp’s Dispatcher.